# What would it take to create juliatex?

Tags: pythontex, julia

In analogy to `pythontex`, what would it take to create `juliatex`?

Comment: `pythontex` exists. What I'm asking is what would have to be done to create a LaTeX extension that would have the same functionality as `pythontex` but uses `julia` instead of `python`.

Comment: According to the `pythontex` documentation, it has already been done, so the answer to the question is "it takes nothing".

Comment: I've removed it.....

Comment: @alephzero ha!  That's awesome.

Comment: @alephzero It seems like that should be turned into an answer.

Comment: @alephzero I'd accept your comment as an answer, though I'd appreciate a short example.

Comment: I've never used pythontex - I just read the manual to see what it was all about. I'm sure there are situations where combining several languages (e.g. LaTeX, lua, python, Julia) together is actually beneficial as well as just "cool", but I try not to go there!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(If alephzero posts an answer, I'll accept his/hers)

But here goes:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[usefamily=julia]{pythontex}

\begin{document}

    \begin{juliacode}
        using LaTeXStrings
        println(L"y=x'\beta+u")
    \end{juliacode}


\end{document}
```

Compile using lualatex, then pythontex, then lualatex.  Ha!

[image]

**EDIT**

A second, somewhat more sophisticated example:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[usefamily=julia]{pythontex}

\begin{document}

    \begin{juliacode}
        srand(1)
        n=100
        X=[ones(n) randn(n)]
        y=X* [1.0;2.0] +randn(n)*3.0
        b=X\y
        println("OLS regression coefficients=",round(b,2))
    \end{juliacode}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please show us something concise, but more useful, `julia` could do for us?

Comment: Will try to put something in later.

Comment: @marsupilam done