# Problem getting pythontex to work with Julia

Tags: pythontex, julia

I was able to get `pythontex` to work fine with Python but am having errors when I try to use it with Julia.  I am running on OSX 10.13.6 with updated texlive and using Texmaker.

I am running this simple example (from [What would it take to create juliatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376396/what-would-it-take-to-create-juliatex))

```latex
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usefamily=julia]{pythontex}

\begin{document}

    \begin{juliacode}
        using LaTeXStrings
        println(L"y=x'\beta+u")
    \end{juliacode}


\end{document}
```

When I first run latex, the error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfkeyssetevalue ...emptoks =\pgfutil@scantokens
\expandafter {\expandafter...
l.1197 }
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

and then when I run pythontex on the file, the error is

```
This is PythonTeX 0.16

----  Messages for julia:default:default  ----
  ERROR: LoadError: syntax: extra token "JuliaTeXUtils" after end of expression
  Stacktrace:
   [1] include at ./boot.jl:326 [inlined]
   [2] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
   [3] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
   [4] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:267
   [5] _start() at ./client.jl:436
* PythonTeX stderr - error on line -130:
```

Any ideas?

The first log file after running latex is ...

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.5.8)  30 JUL 2019 16:20
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test_julia.tex
(./test_julia.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pythontex/pythontex.sty
Package: pythontex 2017/07/20 v0.16 execute and typeset Python code and other l
anguages

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fvextra/fvextra.sty
Package: fvextra 2019/02/04 v1.4 fvextra - extensions and patches for fancyvrb

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count88
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Package: fancyvrb 2019/01/15

Style option: `fancyvrb' v3.2a <2019/01/15> (tvz)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
\FV@CodeLineNo=\count89
\FV@InFile=\read1
\FV@TabBox=\box27
\c@FancyVerbLine=\count90
\FV@StepNumber=\count91
\FV@OutFile=\write3
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty
Package: upquote 2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verba
tim

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package
Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
(textcomp)               5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
(textcomp)               4 = 5 + \texteuro
(textcomp)               3 = 4 + \textohm
(textcomp)               2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
(textcomp)               1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
(textcomp)               0 = TS1 (full)
(textcomp)             Font families with sub-encoding setting implement
(textcomp)             only a restricted character set as indicated.
(textcomp)             Family '?' is the default used for unknown fonts.
(textcomp)             See the documentation for details.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 79.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
Now handling font encoding TS1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding TS1

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu
File: ts1enc.dfu 2018/10/05 v1.2f UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A2 (decimal 162)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00A4 (decimal 164)
   defining Unicode char U+00A5 (decimal 165)
   defining Unicode char U+00A6 (decimal 166)
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00A8 (decimal 168)
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AC (decimal 172)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00AF (decimal 175)
   defining Unicode char U+00B0 (decimal 176)
   defining Unicode char U+00B1 (decimal 177)
   defining Unicode char U+00B2 (decimal 178)
   defining Unicode char U+00B3 (decimal 179)
   defining Unicode char U+00B4 (decimal 180)
   defining Unicode char U+00B5 (decimal 181)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+00B9 (decimal 185)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+00BC (decimal 188)
   defining Unicode char U+00BD (decimal 189)
   defining Unicode char U+00BE (decimal 190)
   defining Unicode char U+00D7 (decimal 215)
   defining Unicode char U+00F7 (decimal 247)
   defining Unicode char U+0192 (decimal 402)
   defining Unicode char U+02C7 (decimal 711)
   defining Unicode char U+02D8 (decimal 728)
   defining Unicode char U+02DD (decimal 733)
   defining Unicode char U+0E3F (decimal 3647)
   defining Unicode char U+2016 (decimal 8214)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
   defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
   defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
   defining Unicode char U+203B (decimal 8251)
   defining Unicode char U+203D (decimal 8253)
   defining Unicode char U+2044 (decimal 8260)
   defining Unicode char U+204E (decimal 8270)
   defining Unicode char U+2052 (decimal 8274)
   defining Unicode char U+20A1 (decimal 8353)
   defining Unicode char U+20A4 (decimal 8356)
   defining Unicode char U+20A6 (decimal 8358)
   defining Unicode char U+20A9 (decimal 8361)
   defining Unicode char U+20AB (decimal 8363)
   defining Unicode char U+20AC (decimal 8364)
   defining Unicode char U+20B1 (decimal 8369)
   defining Unicode char U+2103 (decimal 8451)
   defining Unicode char U+2116 (decimal 8470)
   defining Unicode char U+2117 (decimal 8471)
   defining Unicode char U+211E (decimal 8478)
   defining Unicode char U+2120 (decimal 8480)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+2126 (decimal 8486)
   defining Unicode char U+2127 (decimal 8487)
   defining Unicode char U+212E (decimal 8494)
   defining Unicode char U+2190 (decimal 8592)
   defining Unicode char U+2191 (decimal 8593)
   defining Unicode char U+2192 (decimal 8594)
   defining Unicode char U+2193 (decimal 8595)
   defining Unicode char U+2329 (decimal 9001)
   defining Unicode char U+232A (decimal 9002)
   defining Unicode char U+2422 (decimal 9250)
   defining Unicode char U+25E6 (decimal 9702)
   defining Unicode char U+25EF (decimal 9711)
   defining Unicode char U+266A (decimal 9834)
   defining Unicode char U+FEFF (decimal 65279)
))
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 334.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 349.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 350.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 351.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 352.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 353.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 354.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ccr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 355.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptm sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 356.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pcr sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 357.
Package textcomp Info: Setting phv sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 358.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ppl sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 359.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pag sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 360.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pbk sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 361.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pnc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 362.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pzc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 363.
Package textcomp Info: Setting bch sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 364.
Package textcomp Info: Setting put sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 365.
Package textcomp Info: Setting uag sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 366.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ugq sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 367.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul8 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 368.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul9 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 369.
Package textcomp Info: Setting augie sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 370.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayrom sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 371.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayroms sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 372.

Package textcomp Info: Setting pxr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 373.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 374.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 375.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 376.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 377.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 378.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 379.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmdh sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 380.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 381.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmssq sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 382.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 383.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 384.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhv sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 385.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qag sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 386.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qbk sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 387.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 388.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcs sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 389.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qpl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 390.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qtm sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 391.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qzc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 392.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhvc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 393.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futs sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 394.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 395.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 396.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlh sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 397.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hls sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 398.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlst sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 399.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlct sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 400.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlx sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 401.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlce sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 402.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcn sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 403.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcw sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 404.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcf sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 405.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplx sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 406.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplj sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 407.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 408.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 409.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty
Package: lineno 2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
\linenopenalty=\count92
\output=\toks17
\linenoprevgraf=\count93
\linenumbersep=\dimen103
\linenumberwidth=\dimen104
\c@linenumber=\count94
\c@pagewiselinenumber=\count95
\c@LN@truepage=\count96
\c@internallinenumber=\count97
\c@internallinenumbers=\count98
\quotelinenumbersep=\dimen105
\bframerule=\dimen106
\bframesep=\dimen107
\bframebox=\box28
LaTeX Info: Redefining \\ on input line 3056.
)
\c@FV@TrueTabGroupLevel=\count99
\c@FV@TrueTabCounter=\count100
\FV@TabBox@Group=\box29
\FV@TmpLength=\skip43
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStart=\count101
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStop=\count102
\FV@LoopCount=\count103
\FV@NCharsBox=\box30
\FV@BreakIndent=\dimen108
\FV@BreakIndentNChars=\count104
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeft=\dimen109
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeftNChars=\count105
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRight=\dimen110
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRightNChars=\count106
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeft=\dimen111
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeftNChars=\count107
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRight=\dimen112
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRightNChars=\count108
\c@FancyVerbLineBreakLast=\count109
\FV@LineBox=\box31
\FV@LineIndentBox=\box32
\FV@LineWidth=\dimen113
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count110
\decimalpart=\count111
)
Package: xstring 2019/02/06 v1.83 String manipulations (CT)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfopts/pgfopts.sty
Package: pgfopts 2014/07/10 v2.1a LaTeX package options with pgfkeys

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks18
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks19

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks20
)))
\pgfopts@list@add@a@toks=\toks21
\pgfopts@list@add@b@toks=\toks22
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/newfloat.sty
Package: newfloat 2018/03/04 v1.1a Defining new floating environments (AR)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/currfile/currfile.sty
Package: currfile 2015/04/23 v0.7c Provides the file path elements of the curre
nt input file

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty
Package: filehook 2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
)
\c@currfiledepth=\count112
)
\pytx@codefile=\write4
\openout4 = `test_julia.pytxcode'.

\c@pytx@FancyVerbLineTemp=\count113

! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfkeyssetevalue ...emptoks =\pgfutil@scantokens 
                                                  \expandafter {\expandafter...
l.1197 }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

\c@pytx@py@default@default=\count114
\c@pytx@pycon@default@default=\count115
\c@pytx@sympy@default@default=\count116
\c@pytx@sympycon@default@default=\count117
\c@pytx@pylab@default@default=\count118
\c@pytx@pylabcon@default@default=\count119
\c@pytx@julia@default@default=\count120
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
No file test_julia.aux.
\openout1 = `test_julia.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 8.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.

No file pythontex-files-test_julia/test_julia.pytxmcr.
Run PythonTeX to create it.
Package newfloat Info: New float `listing' with options `fileext=lopytx' on inp
ut line 8.
\c@listing=\count121
\newfloat@ftype=\count122
Package newfloat Info: float type `listing'=8 on input line 8.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count123
\scratchdimen=\dimen114
\scratchbox=\box33
\nofMPsegments=\count124
\nofMParguments=\count125
\everyMPshowfont=\toks23
\MPscratchCnt=\count126
\MPscratchDim=\dimen115
\MPnumerator=\count127
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count128
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks24
) (./test_julia.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5510 strings out of 492616
 94848 string characters out of 6129482
 177493 words of memory out of 5000000
 9394 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4403 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 47i,1n,42p,827b,98s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. I get no errors from your example, just a warning from Julia about deprecated syntax. Can you show the complete `.log` file, perhaps there are some hints there.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for looking at this.  I have added the log file after running latex.  Is there a log file after running pythontex?  Where would that be?

Comment: On second thought that may not have been necessary. I see from searching a bit that there were some problems in a version of `pgf` a few months ago (e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489688), have you updated your TeX Live very recently?

Comment: Hi, your suggestion solved the first error message but unfortunately, there is still an error when running pythontex.  It is the same error as before.  (The first error message went away when I did all the updates for texlive.)

Comment: Does the Julia code work if you run it in a Julia console? I just upgraded Julia to v1.1.1 and it works fine here. I've never really used Julia either, so I can't really make any guesses to what's wrong.

Comment: Yes, it runs fine in a Julia console.  I am also running Julia v1.1.1

Answer (score 3):

The last release of `pythontex` doesn't support more recent versions of Julia.  You can install the development version (https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex) until the next `pythontex` release.

Comment: Hi Geoffrey.  It worked!   Thanks so much for writing pythontex and supporting it!  I look forward to using it for electronics questions that can be easily modified.